# To validate input field in protractor

Tags: google-chrome, protractor

How can I validate the text present in input field using protractor tool?
Can anyone help me in doing this?
I tried the methods which is there already, but didn't work. Please help me out.

Comment: Kindly post your code.

Comment: I got solution to this. Can u tell me the solution to remove special characters in text using protractor tool?

Comment: Kindly post your html code and relevant portions of your protractor spec file and the exact question. You can edit your question to add these details.

Answer (score 0):

`.getAttribute('value')` - it returns a promise

Comment: What is value? I mean what i should replace in place of value?

Comment: `value` is an attribute. Leave it as is.

Comment: can  u send entire line?

Comment: element(by.model('guest.address2')).sendKeys(data.allPatients['address2']);
        expect(element(by.model('guest.address2')).getAttribute('value').toEqual('Zurich, Switzerland'));

Answer (score 0):

Update to @Kacper answer

Sample:

// this is just an example code, adapt it to your needs.

```
element(by.id('input id')).getAttribute('value')
        .then((text) => {
            console.log(text);
        });
```

async way

```
let text = await element(by.id('some id')).getAttribute('value');
console.log('input text : ' + text);
```

Comment: expect(element(by.model('guest.address2')).getAttribute('value').toEqual('Zurich, Switzerland'));   Is this correct?

Comment: i got the solution,but  in logs, text is coming as [object object]. How do i solve this?

Comment: Can u tell me how to remove/replace special characters from input text value using protractor tool

Comment: can you give example about 'special characters' ex: ~$@%! etc.. ?